# increment attribute value dynamically XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to set attributes dynamically, but I can't do it at all. Could you help me? Desirable example :)

Input:

```
<root>
<row>
    <col>v11</col>
    <col>v12</col>
    <col>v13</col>
    <col>v14</col>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col>v21</col>
    <col>v22</col>
    <col>v23</col>
    <col>v24</col>
  </row>
</root>
```

Current XSLT Scheme:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="col">
        <data col="1" row="1">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="col"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <data col="1" row="1">v11</data>
  <data col="1" row="1">v12</data>
  <data col="1" row="1">v13</data>
  <data col="1" row="1">v14</data>
  <data col="1" row="1">v21</data>
  <data col="1" row="1">v22</data>
  <data col="1" row="1">v23</data>
  <data col="1" row="1">v24</data>
</root>
```

How can I dynamically assign attribute values?

I need to make it so:

```
<root>
   <data row="1" col="1">v11</data>
   <data row="1" col="2">v12</data>
   <data row="1" col="3">v13</data>
   <data row="1" col="4">v14</data>
   <data row="2" col="1">v21</data>
   <data row="2" col="2">v22</data>
   <data row="2" col="3">v23</data>
   <data row="2" col="4">v24</data>
</root>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you amend the `apply-templates` for the `col` element to pass in the postion of the `row`...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="col">
    <xsl:with-param name="row" select="position()" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Then, in the template matching `row` you can use this parameter, along with the position of the `col` element

```
<data col="{position()}" row="{$row}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</data>
```

Note the use of curly braces here to create the attributes. These are known as [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates)

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="col">
        <xsl:param name="row" />
        <data col="{position()}" row="{$row}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="col">
        <xsl:with-param name="row" select="position()" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from using `position()`, another way to accomplish this is by using `xsl:number`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="col">
    <data>
      <xsl:attribute name="row">
        <xsl:number count="row" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="col">
        <xsl:number count="col" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="col"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<root>
  <data row="1" col="1">v11</data>
  <data row="1" col="2">v12</data>
  <data row="1" col="3">v13</data>
  <data row="1" col="4">v14</data>
  <data row="2" col="1">v21</data>
  <data row="2" col="2">v22</data>
  <data row="2" col="3">v23</data>
  <data row="2" col="4">v24</data>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's a third way:

```
<xsl:template match="col">
    <data col="{count(preceding-sibling::col)+1}" 
          row="{count(../preceding-sibling::row)+1}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </data>
</xsl:template>
```

What all these solutions have in common is that they compute the output as a function of the input, without maintaining mutable state in program variables. That's the essence of functional programming.